# Nuxt 2 dynamic state.js name

Tags: nuxt.js

I want my state.js & payload.js files to always be at the same location, but still always have a new path.

By default the files are generated like this: `\_nuxt/static/random-id/payload.js`. It causes me some issues to have the path always changing with each new update.

I figured out you can change version of staticAssets to make it generate `\_nuxt/static/1/payload.js`

`staticAssets: {   version: '1', },`

This solves the problem, but in return causes caching issues, since the file isnt forced to refresh with each new deploy.

Optimally i would like to have a hash at the end, like this `\_nuxt/static/1/payload.js?v=random-id`, this way its always located at the same place, but would also be forced to refresh it. Is this possible somehow?

Im aware that you can modify the fileNames in the build property, but this just change everu file expect for these 2 basically https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#filenames